# C pre-processor directives faq

Tags: c

```
#define MAX 20; void main() { printf("MAX"); }
```

Output of this program is:

```
 "20"
```

but I expected it to be:

```
 20;
```

why does semicolon not appear in output ?

Comment: The output of this program is assuredly not `"20"` (unless the undefined behavior caused by `main` having a `void` return type makes it print `"20"`, which is unlikely).  Please post the actual code.

Comment: Everything is wrong about this !!!

Comment: Try copying your code correctly - this isn't going to compile

Comment: really you get "20"  are you sure ?

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> printf("MAX");
> ```

Actually what is printed is `MAX`, since **macros aren't expanded inside quotes**.

Comment: @HarshitSyal No worries. As a rule of thumb it's generally a good idea to run the code you're asking about.

Answer (score 3):

This is WRONG:

```
#define MAX 20; void main() { printf("MAX"); }
```

I suspect maybe you *meant* this:

```
#define MAX 20

void main() 
{ 
  printf("%d\n", MAX); 
}
```

Macros aren't that complex; you can find lots of links.  For example:

- http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html
- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
#define MAX 20; void main() { printf("MAX"); }
```

is not a program.

Comment: It is, however, valid C that defines an object-like macro named `MAX` which is replaced by the token sequence `20; void main() { printf("MAX"); }`.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis - But the next line in the source code would need to be `MAX`. Anyway - bit of a silly question.